# MOSfet thermal design: die-to-package always DRAIN?

Tags: mosfet, thermal, packages

All the MOSfet chips seem to have **substrate = DRAIN**, which means that the heat-dissipation path goes that way. It is assumed that the package DRAIN pin would conduct away most heat from the package to ambient.
Data sheets seem never to confirm this assumption:
[image: MOSfet general die structure]

Large power packages make thermal design obvious: one-of-three leads (DRAIN) is a large metal pad, meant to conduct heat. But small packages like SOT-23, TO-92 etc. have similar-size leads.
On these small non-obvious packages, is it safe to assume that DRAIN pin will *always* get most heated, when considering thermal design?

Answer (score 4):

Most of the heat is generated at the boundary layer between the source and the drain not actually at the drain as you suspect. The way they are made however, the drain presents a nice flat surface to transfer heat through in larger metal tab packages.

For smaller packages, you need to consider the thing as a thermal mass as a whole. All three pins play a part in heat extraction from inside the device. Source and drain are most important, but the gate also adds a thermal release path.

[image]

With some packages, like the SOT-223 shown above, the drain is a harder connection to the die itself and will give the most direct thermal conduction path. The others are bonded through wires and heat transfer is more through the package to the pin. As such the pins are cooling the package more than the die.. but it all counts.

Comment: Yes, your SOT-223 package shows a good thermal path to the TAB. Do not other pkg (SOT23, TO-92) always bond die to one of the 3 leads of the lead frame? All MOSfet dice I've seen show only wirebonding pads for SOURCE & GATE, not DRAIN. I'm assuming DRAIN has de facto electrical & thermal connection to the lead frame, providing a superior thermal path compared to SOURCE or GATE.

Comment: The SOT-223 has two Drain pins: 2 (middle) and 4 (opposite side). Should I connect both on the PCB or is it enough to connect the pin 4? How wide should the connection trace between pin 2 and 4 be, will there be a significant current between the two?

Answer (score 0):

The thermal resistance of bond-wires (thru a 25 micron gold wire) can easily be 10,000 degreesC per watt. The epoxy package has Rthermal 200X that of copper. Think about some finite-element modeling; SPICE works great for 2_D models.